# Ace editor 'named entity expected got none' error

Tags: html, ace-editor

I was using ace editor to write some code, but when wrote `&` in a URL the editor gave me this error: **named entity expected got none**. I tried everything I knew about: changing `&` to `&amp;`, `&` to `%26`, but nothing worked. Here's what I wrote:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Xanh+Mono&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Does anybody know what to do?

Comment: For the font importers, change `&` to `%26` works for me when I used some google fonts.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work

Comment: I knew you didn't work, but worked for me. Since you are the only post related to `named entity expected got none`, I commented a possible answer for others. If I knew your problem exactly, I was going to answer instead :P

Comment: Ah, okay, got it

Answer (score 28):

replace each `&` character with this `&amp;`

Comment: I meant : & a m p ;

Comment: if you read the question you'll realize he already tried that approach... you should provide an alternative solution or an in-depth explanation on why you believe that should work.

Comment: Short and apt answer.. Kudos

Answer (score 0):

Try "& # 43 ;" or "& plus ;" in place of the "+" sign.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31993728)

Answer (score 0):

changing & to %26 is my best way, worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

replace all of & symbol to `&amp;`

it has many sol but idk do it. it can